# connect my connected keycloack user to another keycloack without login in again

Tags: angular, spring, keycloak, single-sign-on

I m currently running 2 spring-angular-keycloack application in different docker container
how can I directly connect to the second application while I m already connected to my first application and get all the user information to my second keycloack configuration

I tried using identity provider and broker but when I wa t to connect to my second application I get the login page and button to the identity provider

I expect: while I m connected to my first application with keycloack, i can click to a valid link that get me directly to the home page of my second application without login in again